# How do I insert acronyms/tooltips in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I have Korean words on my blog, and I would like to show the romanization either in the status bar or as a tooltip on a mouse-over. This text does not hyper-link to anything.

On certain websites I have seen acronyms that have a special dotted underline. When you place the mouse over these words the full, expanded word is shown in the browser status bar. I would also be happy if a tooltip popped up with the romanization.

How can I achieve this effect simply on Blogger? I am using MS Live Writer to compose my blog entries. In your answer, please include how well browsers support your solution.

---

**Update:** I modified [eagle's solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5438/how-do-i-insert-acronyms-tooltips-in-blogger/5439#5439) slightly:

```
span.korean {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
}​
```

and added it to Blogger Template Designer's "Add custom CSS." The result looks like [this](http://www.leftium.com/2010/08/dragon-flies-and-praying-mantises.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an HTML feature. You can either use the [`<acronym>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_acronym.asp) tag, or a `<span>` element. If it's not an acronym, I'd recommend using `<span>` with a custom `class` attribute. The trick is to place the text you want to appear in the hint as the `title` attribute.

Here's an example of the HTML:

```
Can I get this <span class="myclass" title="as soon as possible">ASAP</span>?
```

Now to get it formatted with an underline, you need to add this style anywhere in your HTML, preferably only once in your template:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .myclass {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style​: dashed;
  }​
</style>
```

This should work in all of the major browsers.

Comment: warning: copy-pasting the code does not work because there is a hidden &#8203; character!

Comment: Chrome and IE 8 do not render <acronym> with a visible bottom border.

Comment: The `acronym` tag has been dropped in HTML5. The `abbr` tag should be used instead (supported in IE7+ and all other browsers).